# Android live video streaming to Facebook with text Overlay

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, live-streaming, android-ffmpeg

I had developed Android application that broadcast live video from android application to facebook. It is working fine, now I want to draw text on live video or pass that text to Facebook and display below the live video.

I am getting text using websocket, Whenever text comes from websocket, immediately I want to post that text to Facebook Live video, one way to do this is using FFMpeg

```
-vf "drawtext=fontsize=40:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='hello world':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2"
```

I feel this will make the video slower.

In android application I am using this code, to get RTMP Url for broadcasting...

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        "/"+Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()+"/live_videos",
                        new JSONObject("{\"title\":\"Today's Live Video\",\"description\":\"TV app.\"}"),
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StreamingActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
}
```

Is there any way to draw the text in the live stream video or pass the text to facebook and display it below the live video as text overlay.

Comment: Sorry not related to your question, It is mentioned here [Fb platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#liveAPI) that you should not use the API to stream directly from a mobile phone or tablet camera to Facebook. My question is, is it working properly?